# How can I calculate area enclosed by three curves in WolframAlpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to calculate the region enclosed by $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$, $y=x$ and $y=4$ for $x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 4]$ How can I do this?

I know I can use definite integral for this task but I want a general formula that I can apply in WolframAlpha to check my calculations. Something like `find area between y=1/x^2, y=x, y=4 from 1/2 to 4` but working. `find area between y=1/x^2, y=x, y=4` works and returns `(unbounded)` as expected but I also need a way to specify interval.

Comment: Maybe because area is unbounded. See the plot: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx,+y%3D1%2Fx%5E2,+y%3D4 I cannot identify a bounded area.

Comment: Wolfram products have serious issues that they have little interest in fixing.

Comment: @callculus - You're right, I edited the question.

Comment: @user509051 There is no other choice than calculate them seperately: [First area](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+y%3D1%2Fx%5E2+and+y%3D4,+0.5%3Cx%3C1) and  [Second area](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+y%3Dx+and+y%3D4,+domain+1%3Cx%3C4) Then add the values.

Answer (score 1):

The area is
$$\int_{1/2}^1 \left(4-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx+\int_1^4(4-x)\,dx=\frac{11}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, but do you know a command for WolframAlpha that can compute this for some number of functions for any interval? I know I can use definite integral to calculate the area but I'm looking for a command to check my calculations in WolframAlpha e.g. something like `find area between y=1/x^2, y=x, y=4 from 0 to 4` (this doesn't work though, just an example).

Comment: `Integrate[4-1/x^2,{x,1/2,1}]+Integrate[4-x,{x,1,4}]`